# Basic ssh tunneling through generic linux ssh server/client

Tags: ssh, remote-login

I'm use my home pc to connect to the corporate server with ssh doing something like:

```
    ssh -p 2424 user@corporatehost.com
```

Then I log in remotely once more to another server in the corporate network:

```
    ssh internalcorporatehost
```

Can I set a ssh tunnel to do this in one step, or are there any other ways to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Set up `user@corporatehost.com` as a proxy:

```
ssh -o 'ProxyCommand ssh -p 2424 user@corporatehost.com nc %h %p' internalcorporatehost
```

This is best used through an alias in `~/.ssh/config`, so you can simply type `ssh ich`:

```
Host ich
HostName internalcorporatehost
User user_name_on_internalcorporatehost
ProxyCommand ssh -p 2424 user@corporatehost.com nc %h %p
```

`nc` is the [netcat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat) command, which must be installed on the gateway machine. If it's not available, install any of the versions floating around (you only need basic functionality). You may need to indicate the full path to the `nc` binary (e.g. `/home/oleg/bin/nc`).

If your ssh client is Putty, [this answer at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010808/ssh-tunnelling-chain/1122282#1122282) should help.

Answer (score 1):

A very easy solution is to just **tunnel** an `SSH` command through an other `SSH` command using the `-t` flag.

```
ssh -p 2424 -t user@corporatehost.com  ssh internalcorporatehost
```

Makes it very easy and you don't need any further config.