# Tunnelling X11 through an SSH gateway with no X11 install

Tags: ssh, xorg, x11-forwarding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Skip over intermediate server via SSH](https://superuser.com/questions/192735/skip-over-intermediate-server-via-ssh)

At my university we have an SSH gateway for remote access to our departmental Linux network.  The gateway itself has a very minimal install of Linux so we generally SSH into unused workstation.

The problem is that sometimes I want to use graphical applications remotely and the SSH gateway does not have X11 installed on it so using ssh -X doesn't seem work.

Is there any way to tunnel X11 through from one of the workstations through the SSH gateway?

Comment: See [Forward SSH traffic through a middle machine.](http://superuser.com/questions/107679) or [Basic ssh tunneling through generic linux ssh server/client](http://superuser.com/questions/190351). The gateway doesn't need to (indeed, cannot) know anything about X and other forwardings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you're essentially SSH'ing twice at least?  Like you --> gateway --> workstation?

I think you'll have to experiment with [SSH tunneling](http://souptonuts.sourceforge.net/sshtips.htm).

Comment: that's right. I'll have a look at the link