# File Transfer with a double SSH login

Tags: windows-7, linux, file-transfer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Basic ssh tunneling through generic linux ssh server/client](https://superuser.com/questions/190351/basic-ssh-tunneling-through-generic-linux-ssh-server-client)

I'm have trouble transfering files again from my work PC, which is a linux machine to my home windows PC.
My work has changed it so I now need to SSH twice before I can access my PC.

So I need to:

> ssh username@server.name 
>   password: xxxxx

I then need to do it again.

> ssh computer_name 
>   password: xxxxx

I've tried accessing directly via my computers IP but to of no avail.

Is there a way I can use pscp or file zilla to ssh twice so I can transfer files?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can handle this by using **ssh forwarding** or **ssh tunnelling** - use those as search terms here (or in google) - or review the SSH documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Log in via ssh -L 222:computerIP:22 server.name

then from same machine as last command, and with last connection still open in anouther window use

ssh 127.0.0.1 -p 222

If you want to use scp to copy files, use scp -P 222 user@127.0.0.1

I believe this'll work, never tried it.

p.s: You can use -L 22 if you want, but i always pick anouther port on the assumption your using the first machine as an ssh server as also.